# Is it theoretically feasible to establish transfer function of a BLDC motor under torque control with frequency response?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, transfer-function

I am working on my assignment of Control theory at school. I designed a gimbal using BLDC motor, it works fine now but I need to demonstrate how the PID parameters were determined in my paper.

After looking into the SimpleFOC documentation, I realize that the closed-loop position & velocity control is simply by adding a PID controller to the **torque control loop**.

And I find that the input of the torque control loop is **voltage**, and the output is **velocity** of the motor ([which acts like a DC motor](https://docs.simplefoc.com/voltage_torque_mode#expected-motor-behavior)). So, I think it might be feasible to take the **BLDC motor + torque control loop** as a black box, measure its frequency response, and then use the System Identification toolbox in Matlab to obtain the transfer function.

If it's theoretically feasible to do that, then I have got one more question. How can I work out the value in **Bode magnitude plot**, since it defines as (output magnitude)/(input magnitude), but the input is voltage(V), output is velocity(Rad/s), so I am confusing.